# $\lim_{n \to +\infty}2^n\sin(2^{-n})$

Tags: calculus, limits

Software tells me that $\lim_{n \to +\infty}2^n\sin(2^{-n}) = 1$.

Can someone give me a hint on where to start to actually show this is true?

I was working on the following problem:

$$ \prod_{n=0}^\infty\cos(2^{-n})$$

And I used,

$$\sin(1) = 2\sin(2^{-1})\cos(2^{-1}) $$
$$\sin(1) = 2^{n}\sin(2^{-n})\cos(2^{-n}) \cdots \cos(2^{-1})$$
$$\sin(1)\cos(1) = 2^{n}\sin(2^{-n})\cos(2^{-n}) \cdots \cos(2^{-1})\cos(1)$$

So if $$\lim_{n \to +\infty}2^nsin(2^{-n}) = 1$$
then,
$$\sin(1)\cos(1) = \prod_{n=0}^\infty\cos(2^{-n})$$.

I feel like this should be relatively simple, but I'm pulling a blank.

Comment: Hint: Our expression is $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ where $x=2^{-n}$.

Comment: Ahh I see! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\sin {1\over x}=\lim_{y\to 0}{\sin y\over y}=1$ by taking $y={1\over x}$

Answer (score 1):

Perform a substitution $2^n=t$ then rewrite the limit.
The term becomes $t\sin(1/t)$ with t→ infinity.
If you then perform another sub, say $t=1/v$, where v goes to zero, you will recognize a familiar standard limit which is 1